# Prove $P(\{X\ge t\}\cup\{Y\ge t\})\le t^{-2}(1+\sqrt{1-r^2})$ where $r$ is the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ centered with unit variance

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, correlation

> Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be random variables with variances $\mathbb{D}\xi$ and $\mathbb{D}\eta$, and correlation coefficient $\rho$. Show that $$\mathbb{P}(\{\xi - \mathbb{E}\xi \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{\mathbb{D}\xi} \} \cup  \{ \eta - \mathbb{E}\eta \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{\mathbb{D}\eta}) \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}(1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}).$$

So, if I am right,  I see a connection with $$\mathbb{E}\max\{\xi^2,\eta^2\}\leq 1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}.$$ But actually don't know how to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG after renormalizing, both variables have mean zero and dispersions equal to one, so we can write this as
$$
\def\e{\varepsilon}
P(\xi\ge \e\cup \eta\ge \e)=P(\max(\xi,\eta)\ge\e)\le P(\max(\xi^2,\eta^2)\ge \e^2).
$$
Now, use Markov's inequality to relate this to $E[\max(\xi^2,\eta^2)]$.

Comment: Thank you. How to prove right inequality's side I know, but do I need to find $E(max\{ (\xi,\eta)  \}$? If yes, then  I have problems with it... I did everything the same, but don't know how much is $\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{\xi}\sqrt{\eta})$. Is it equal to $\sqrt{\rho}$?

Comment: No, you only need to deal with $E[\max(\xi^2,\eta^2)]$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then I done with it. Thank you for your help